# What is the meaning of "ugg"?

Tags: meaning

What does the word *ugg* mean? Does it mean *made in China*?

Here is an example from a Skype group of my company:

> A: ... sesion ...
>   B: misspelling of session -> sesion
>   C: ugg!

A is a Chinese, B and C are both native English speakers.

Comment: Can you give some example usages about `ugg`? I have never heard it before.

Comment: It looks like kind of *ugh*.

Answer (score 7):

Spelled as "ugg", the only interpretation is Ugg boots, as Kosmonaut mentioned. (I believe the original brand-name boots are/were not made in China, but I'm sure countless imitations are.)

However, given the context you posted, another interpretation is possible: this may be a misspelling or alternate spelling of "ugh", an interjection denoting disgust.

Comment: It's also deliciously ironic. It might well have been posted as, "You're speling is attroshus!"

Answer (score 5):

[Ugg](http://www.uggaustralia.com/) is a shoe brand. The company makes sheepskin boots.

[image]

(I have no idea where you got the idea that it means "made in China"...)

Comment: Hi Kosmonaut, I've added the context. Could you please look at it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is "ugh" which is a noise one makes in disgust. Here is an example of usage: http://perlypalms.com/herbie/women-swoon/19a-04.jpg

( above image credits to this page: http://perlypalms.com/herbie/pix.pl?women-swoon )

Answer (score 0):

Uggs are made in Australia, and is Australian slang for "ugly".

Answer (score 0):

As reported also by others, Ugg is a brand of boots.

The NOAD reports that the origin of *Ugg boot* is 1960s, from the name of cartoon characters (*Ugh*).

Similarly, that user wrote *ugg* instead of *ugh*.